# Scrollpane in javafx is a burden on the RAM when displaying a big collection of items and views

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8, scrollview

I am developing a library application using javafx, where the user can import epub files, and he gets a library with shelves, where each shelf contains at most 6 books. I am using a scrollpane inside it a VBox containing additional VBoxes(each one resembles a shelf) each one contains a image(which is the shelf),and above it an HBox containing images of book covers. I tried with the listview but it doesn't work since a listview lists a list of items that you click on one of them, and in my case the item will be the entire shelf which contains several books(I want to handle the click on each book individually). Sorry for the long description.
[This is the image represention of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDCmM.png)

Comment: You really should think about trying `ListView` again; you need a virtualized control. You can disable the row selection behavior by supplying your own `MultipleSelectionModel` (and possibly `FocusModel`). You could also style the `ListView` differently so, while items can still be selected/focused, it doesn't _look_ like they're selected/focused.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/sedj601/ContactsFx/tree/master/src/contactsfx). It can give you some ideas of how to implement what you need using `ListView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options for this; but likely the best is using a `ListView` as the comments suggest.

The sample application below will demonstrate one way to do so. I have not done any work on styling the `ListView`, however. Mostly because I am not very proficient in CSS myself (I welcome edits and suggestions), but also because that is out of the scope of this fairly vague question.

Combining a `ListView` with a custom `CellFactory`, you are able to build a layout for each "shelf" in your library; the `ListView` will display each row using that layout.

There are additional comments in the code below.

> **Library Example MCVE:**

**LibraryExample.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.util.List;

public class LibraryExample extends Application {

    // Our list of shelves that will be displayed in the ListView
    private final ObservableList<Shelf> shelves = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Build a list of 100 sample books. This list could come from a database or other outside source, of course
        List<Book> books = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            books.add(new Book("Book #" + i, new ImageView("sample/generic-cover.png")));
        }

        // We will now create our shelves for the books. We will limit the number of books to 6 per shelf. This uses
        // the subList method of our List to grab every 6 books until we run out.
        int index = 0;
        while (index < books.size()) {

            // Make sure there are at least 6 books remaining, otherwise, we need to get the subList up to the size of
            // the original list.
            final int numToAdd = (index + 6 <= books.size() ? index + 6 : books.size());
            shelves.addAll(new Shelf(books.subList(index, numToAdd)));
            index += 6;
        }

        // Now, let's create our ListView that will hold our shelves.
        ListView<Shelf> listView = new ListView<>();
        VBox.setVgrow(listView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // Now for the magic. We will override the CellFactory for the ListView so we can provide our own layout
        // for each row
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Shelf>, ListCell<Shelf>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Shelf> call(ListView<Shelf> param) {
                return new ShelfListCell();
            }
        });

        listView.setItems(shelves);

        root.getChildren().add(listView);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(700);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class ShelfListCell extends ListCell<Shelf> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Shelf shelf, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(shelf, empty);

        if (shelf == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {

            // Here, we will build our layout for each shelf
            VBox root = new VBox(5);
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.setPadding(new Insets(5));

            HBox hBox = new HBox(20);
            hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            hBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));

            // Add image for each each book on this shelf to the layout
            for (Book book : shelf.getBooks()) {

                // Get the image of the book and add a simple click listener
                ImageView cover = book.getCoverImage();
                cover.setPreserveRatio(true);
                cover.setFitHeight(100);
                cover.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Clicked " + book.getTitle()));

                hBox.getChildren().add(book.getCoverImage());
            }

            root.getChildren().addAll(hBox, new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL));

            // Set the cell to display our layout
            setGraphic(root);

        }
    }
}
```

---

**Book.java:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Book {

    private final StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final ObjectProperty<ImageView> coverImage = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public Book(String title, ImageView coverImage) {
        this.title.set(title);
        this.coverImage.set(coverImage);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title.get();
    }

    public StringProperty titleProperty() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.set(title);
    }

    public ImageView getCoverImage() {
        return coverImage.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<ImageView> coverImageProperty() {
        return coverImage;
    }

    public void setCoverImage(ImageView coverImage) {
        this.coverImage.set(coverImage);
    }
}
```

---

**Shelf.java:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.util.List;

public class Shelf {

    // Set max number of books per shelf
    private final static int MAX_BOOKS = 6;

    // Our observable list of books
    private final ListProperty<Book> books = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    public Shelf(List<Book> books) {
        this.books.addAll(books);
    }

    public void addBooks(Book... books) {
        this.books.addAll(books);
    }

    public static int getMaxBooks() {
        return MAX_BOOKS;
    }

    public ObservableList<Book> getBooks() {
        return books.get();
    }

    public ListProperty<Book> booksProperty() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(ObservableList<Book> books) {
        this.books.set(books);
    }
}
```

---

> **The Result:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the effort you did to show me how to do it!